# silverlight richtextbox display rtf

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have looked around for awhile and have not seen anything yet. I was hoping someone came up with something by now that can guide me in the right direction. I have an rtf string pulled from my database. I was trying to find a way to display this rtf string formatted in silverlights richtextbox.

From what I have read silverlights richtext stores formatted text as xaml and not true rtf. Has anyone found a work around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the standard RichTextBox for SL cannot load the RTF text.  I would suggest that you find for a custom solution.  For example, our DXRichEdit control is able to work with RTF, Docx, Doc and many other formats.  You will find a demo of this control at:

[RichEdit Demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/DemoCenter/Silverlight/?RichEditDemo)

Comment: Yes I am currently using your control but it is very slow to load.

Comment: @Jim, hm, it is very interesting, can you please post your rtf so that we can download and check the control's performance using your file?  We will let you know our results...

Comment: There is no loading it is a blank editor. It is just the rendor time it takes to open

Comment: do you mean that the application which uses the DXRichEdit starts slowly?

Comment: no when my form that has teh richedit loads it takes awhile. Provide me your email and I will email you the xaml

Comment: Sent the xaml to the email address provided

Comment: @DevExpressTeam let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1222/discussion-between-jim-and-devexpress-team)

Comment: I see it.  We will take a look at it shortly and return back

Comment: @Jim, I've answered in you in the support center.  If you are using an old version, please try to install the latest one (11.1.5) and check the performance...